# Binding to a member variable

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind

I am confused as to what boost::bind does when we bind to member variables. With binding to member function, we essentially create a function object, and then call it passing to it the arguments that are provided or delayed and substituted via placeholders.

But what does this expression do behind the scenes:

```
boost::bind(&std::pair::second, _1);
```

What gets substituted in place of the placeholder _1?

I found this while reading this example from an article on boost::bind:

```
void print_string(const std::string& s) {
  std::cout << s << '\n';
}

std::map<int,std::string> my_map;
my_map[0]="Boost";
my_map[1]="Bind";

std::for_each(
  my_map.begin(),
  my_map.end(),
   boost::bind(&print_string, boost::bind(
      &std::map<int,std::string>::value_type::second,_1)));
```

[source](http://www.totalformat.com/forum/coding-design-graphics/40763-how-boost-bind-library-can-improve-your-c-programs.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Behind the scenes it is using a member pointer and applying it to the passed in argument. It is quite complex in the context of binds, so here is a simple example of pointer to member usage:

```
int main()
{
   std::pair< int, int > p1 = make_pair( 1, 2 );
   std::pair< int, int > p2 = make_pair( 2, 4 );
   int std::pair<int,int>::*ptr = &std::pair<int,int>::second; // pointer to second member

   std::cout << p1.*ptr << std::endl; // 2 dereference pointer to member 
   std::cout << p2.*ptr << std::endl; // 4 dereference pointer to member
}
```

Behind the scenes bind is composing different calls. The resulting functor takes the dereference of std::map<>::iterator (of type std::pair< const key_type, value_type >). That is passed to the inner bind, that dereferences the member pointer, thus returning `(*it).second` to the outer bind that passes that value to the `print_string` method for the final call: `print_string( (*it).second )`.

`(*it)` is actually the `_1` you asked about. All `_#` are placeholders, that is, the result of bind will be a functor that will take as many arguments as different placeholders exist in the order defined by the number of placeholder. In the example you gave, the resulting functor takes a single argument `_1`.

Answer (score 2):

```
boost::bind(&std::pair<U,V>::second, _1);
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
std::pair<U,V> p -> p.second
```

ie. it is a function (object) that maps a `pair<U,V>` to its    `second` member.